# js regex get string from txt start with "start" end with "end" only once

Tags: javascript, regex

**Hello ,**

I have text and I need to find in it a string start with "start" and end with "end". only the first occurrence.
if the string is :

```
 "just test ... bla ...bla start some txt .... end more text "
"just test ... bla ...bla start some txt .... end more text ".match(/start(.*)end/)
```

i am getting the correct answer ,array with 2 items:

```
 array[0]="start some txt .... end"
 array[1]=" some txt .... "
```

this is perfect.
when the text contains more the one "end":

```
"just test ... bla ...bla start some txt .... end more text  xxxx end blue fff  ...end"
```

I cant get the right string whats happening is that the `.match(/start(.*)end/)` return all the string from the first "start" to last "end" instead of to the first "end" : 
return : `"start some txt .... end more text  xxxx end blue fff  ...end"`
what I need is only the first occurrence :

```
"start some txt .... end"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/start(.*?)end/
```

the `?` makes it "non-greedy" meaning it'll match as little as possible

Answer (score 1):

Try non-greedy matching:

```
/start(.*?)end/
```